# Interpreting expression in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

Im stuck on this expression that someone else wrote, i seriously can´t figure out what it does?
What is/ is not empty and what does it count?

countIf(IsEmpty && ActivityTypeId == 1, ContainerId)

countIf(!IsEmpty && ActivityTypeId == 1, ContainerId)

Thanks!

Comment: can you please add Images of your pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countIf` is an aggregate function in azure data factory mapping data flow which counts the number of rows in the dataset based on the condition. In your expression, it counts the number of `ContainerId` when conditions are true.

- **`countIf(IsEmpty && ActivityTypeId == 1, ContainerId)`**: This expression counts the number of ContainerId where the  `IsEmpty`  field is true and the  `ActivityTypeId`  field is equal to 1. Here the `IsEmpty` is supposed to be a Boolean type. And, the `activityTypeId` is the integer field.
- **`countIf(!IsEmpty && ActivityTypeId == 1, ContainerId)`**: This expression counts the number of records where the `IsEmpty` field is false and the `ActivityTypeId` field is equal to 1.
- The `!` operator is a logical NOT operator that negates the `IsEmpty` field value. The `&&` operator is a logical AND operator that combines the two conditions.

This is tested with sample input data  and below is the observation.

Input data:

| batch | ContainerId | ActivityTypeId | IsEmpty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | true |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | false |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | true |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | true |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | false |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | false |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | true |
| 1 | 8 | 1 | false |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | true |
| 1 | 10 | 2 | true |

There are 4 records where `IsEmpty` is `true` and `ActivityTypeId` is `1`, so the first expression will return the value `4`; There are 3 records where `IsEmpty` is `false` and `ActivityTypeId` is `1`, so the second expression will return the value `3`.

- Conditions are given in aggregate Transformation.

[image: img]

- Output of the aggregate transformation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! I was so sure that IsEmpty was a function but i also see now that i have a column called IsEmpty in an incoming stream.